# How I Use Microsoft Web Platform Installer offline?

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-web-platform

I have a server that's behind a Windows 2012 firewall without Internet access. I need to install PHP on it, and would prefer to use the Web Platform Installer if possible. I can't find any recent information on how to do this, save for this article:

http://www.ca.com/us/support/ca-support-online/product-content/knowledgebase-articles/tec1193892.aspx

When I run the first part, I am able to generate a dump file; however, the file is only 1k and is not readable. As the WebPICMD runs I can see the list being output the screen very quickly, but for some reason it doesn't make it to the file..
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer>WebPICMD.exe /List /ListOption:All>C:\temp\dump.txt

Any feedback on this?

Comment: You can install 5.6 from it. We are doing product development and trying to keep stuff standardized if we can. What I'm asking for is doable, just need updated instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find update documentation for the offline features of web platform installer [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-v4-command-line-webpicmdexe-rtw-release)

I was able to run the following on my laptop to download the offline install cache for PHP56. It automatically downloads all possible prerequisites.

```
WebPICMD.exe /Offline /Products:PHP56 /Path:C:\webpioff
```

You can copy this folder to the server without internet access, launch web platform installer and click the options link on the bottom. You can then browse to and select the file "C:\webpioff\feeds\latest\webproductlist.xml" as your primary feed. Or, in command line:

```
WebPICMD.exe /Install /Products:PHP56 /XML:C:\webpioff\feeds\latest\webproductlist.xml
```